Backfill null values with next non null value
Using SQL Server 2019, how can I backfill all null values with the next non null value.
Ex. for 1/13/2024 - 1/15/2024 values for a_usd would be backfilled by 1/16/2024 a_usd column value. 1/1/2024 would be backfilled by 1/2/2024 a_usd column value.
Here is my code:
--create CTE for historical price indices
with init_price_cte as (
select distinct
    i.index_name,
    format(hp.start_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd') as start_date,
    hp.price

from idx_historical_prices hp
    inner join idx_def i on hp.index_id = i.index_id
    inner join ref_source s on hp.ref_source = s.id_number
    left join index_location l on hp.index_location=l.index_loc_id

where i.index_name in ('NG_GD_STANFIELD', 'NG_GD_AECO.USD') and year(start_date) = year(getdate())
),

--aeco cad conversion rate to usd
currency_cte as (
select 
    fx_rate_mid,
    fx_rate_date
from EndurApps.dbo.HourlyCalendar cal
    left join dbo.idx_historical_fx_rates r on fx_rate_date = cal.StartUtc
where year(StartUtc) = year(getdate()) and r.currency_id=51
),

price_cte as (
select 
    a.start_date,
    a.price as aeco_cad_price,
    round((a.price/currency_cte.fx_rate_mid), 3) as aeco_usd_price,
    b.price as stan_price,
    round((b.price - (a.price/currency_cte.fx_rate_mid)), 3) as stan_spread
from init_price_cte as a
join init_price_cte as b
    on a.start_date = b.start_date
    and a.index_name = 'NG_GD_AECO.USD'
    and b.index_name = 'NG_GD_STANFIELD'
left join currency_cte as currency_cte
    on a.start_date = currency_cte.fx_rate_date
)

select * from price_cte

Here is the output:
start_date  a_cad   a_usd
2024-01-01  1.635   NULL
2024-01-02  1.635   1.228
2024-01-03  1.735   1.299
2024-01-04  1.91    1.43
2024-01-05  2.4     1.798
2024-01-06  2.27    NULL
2024-01-07  2.27    NULL
2024-01-08  2.27    1.698
2024-01-09  2.585   1.93
2024-01-10  3.185   2.38
2024-01-11  3.455   2.577
2024-01-12  3.595   2.685
2024-01-13  13.275  NULL
2024-01-14  13.275  NULL
2024-01-15  13.275  NULL
2024-01-16  13.275  9.846 

